# function.querySnapshot is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting the following error with the code posed below: `querySnapshot.forEach is not a function`. I also tried using the `documentSnapshot` function and it did not work either.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var rootref =  firebase.firestore().collection("deneme").doc("2");
    var wholeData = []
    rootref.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        wholeData.push(doc.data())
         });
    })};

render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.wholeData}
         `renderItem={this.wholeData}/>
      </View>
    );
}};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're loading a single document, so the argument passed to your callback is a `DocumentSnapshot` and not a `QuerySnapshot`.

To push the document to your array:

```
var rootref = firebase.firestore().collection("deneme").doc("2");
var wholeData = []
rootref.get().then(function(doc){
  wholeData.push(doc.data())
});
```

To load the entire collection and push it to the array:

```
var rootref = firebase.firestore().collection("deneme");
var wholeData = []
rootref.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    wholeData.push(doc.data())
  });
});
```

Comment: This resolved the issue but i dont get any results. Page seems to be blank.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, that could be caused by many things. Check your JavaScript console for errors, and step through the `then()` callback in a debugger to get an idea as to why this may happen.

Comment: Yeah i checked the array its full but cant render the values.